# pandas - drop duplicate rows in a dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I have one df like this:

```
>>> df1

        col_1   col_2    size_col  other_col
0        aaa     abc       4          zxc
1        aaa     abc       3          xcv
2        aaa     abc       1          cvb
3        bbb     bbc       7          vbn
4        bbb     bbc       3          bnm
5        ccc     cbc       1          asd
6        ddd     dbc       9          sdf
7        ccc     cbc       3          dfg
8        ccc     cbc       1          fgh
```

and want a df like this:

```
>>> df2

        col_1   col_2    size_col  other_col
0        aaa     abc       4          zxc
3        bbb     bbc       7          vbn
6        ddd     dbc       9          sdf
7        ccc     cbc       3          dfg
```

Explanation:
I want to all drop the where `col_1` and `col_2` have similar values, and retain the rows where 'size_col' is greatest for all the duplicate bunch. so, from above example, for the rows, where  `col_1` and `col_2` has `aaa` and `abc`, I need to retain the row where `size_col` has biggest value. or put other way, i need to group by `col_1` and `col_2` columns, then for each group, retain only the row where `other_col` have biggest value for the group.

How do I do this efficiently for a df with around 5 million rows and 7 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1.loc[df1.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'])['size_col'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: all that's left is speed timing; over to u :grin:

Comment: @sammywemmy Haha! I also almost fell into that `drop_duplicate` trap :P

Comment: i have another numerical columns too. how do i ensure that the `max()` part actually takes `size_col` and not something else?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala - Check dupe.

Comment: @U12-Forward - Can you convert to wiki?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala Check my last part

Comment: @jezrael yes!!!

Comment: @U12-Forward Super, now I can edit.